# Trying to test a WebMethod and ajax call to it locally and getting 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a web forms project, and I'm trying to teach myself how I can manually POST to send and receive data from a page using ajax, as apposed to doing it in the backend code.  I believe I'm on the right track, but I'm getting a 500 internal server error.

I've checked Event Viewer and am not seeing any errors there, along with having breakpoints in the page_load and application_error which neither are ever hit.  With this being my first Web Handler, I probably made a stupid mistake, but I followed a few guides to create it.  Basically, I just created a new web form, added reference to System.Web.Services, and included the [WebMethod] attribute before the method declaration.

If anyone has any advice, that would be wonderful and greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace YODA.Code
{
    public partial class myekc_api : BusinessLogicLayer.UserPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                string innerHtml = "<table>";
                foreach (string s in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
                    innerHtml += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", s, Request.QueryString[s]);
            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GettingStartedDepartments(List<string> departments)
        {
            string queryString = "?";
            int i = 1;
            foreach(string s in departments)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                    queryString += string.Format("department{0}={1}", i.ToString(), s);
                else
                    queryString += string.Format("&department{0}={1}", i.ToString(), s);
            }

            return queryString;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GettingStartedDepartments(string departments)
        {
            return departments;
        }
    }
}
```

I added to second method for testing as I wasn't sure if I was properly sending the data so it would be interpreted as a List.

and here is the ajax:

```
$("#btnSubmitDepartments").click(function() {
    var txaVal = $("#txaDepartments").val();
    var list = $("#txaDepartments").val().split('\n');
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list});
    console.log($("#txaDepartments").val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:57184/Code/api.aspx/GettingStartedDepartments",
        //data: jsonText,
        data: txaVal,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { window.location.replace("http://localhost:57184/Code/api.aspx/GettingStartedDepartments".append(data.d)) },
        error: function(data) { alert("Error!") }
    })
});
```

Thanks again, I really appreciate any help.
Andy

Comment: Are you able to post succesfully to the simpler "test" method?

Comment: `console.log( $("#txaDepartments").val().split('\n') )` please. you getting a string array?

Comment: Um I'm not sure if I'm getting a string array or not, but the code I pasted isn't posting the array.  I created the more simple test method to just receive a string in case that was the problem.  I'm just posting the string from the text area, and still getting the 500 internal server error.  Thanks

Comment: So I did that console.log and it was indeed a string array.  I got ["Test", "Test 2"]

Comment: Does anyone think this could have something to do with using IIS express?